# .NET custom combo box after OnPaint

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

We have an application running on a windows 8 VM that makes use of custom combo boxes while using the .NET framework. There seems to be an odd bug where, when RDPing into the VM all the text in the combo boxes on the screen become selected (for our custom combo boxes only, not .NET's combo boxes).

After stepping through, it seems this happens RIGHT after the OnPaint method for a given combo box. It's weird because it only happens when remotely connecting. Anyway I want to have something like an AfterPaint method(if something like that exists) where I check if the text is selected and if the combo box doesn't have focus, then I remove the selection (SelectionLength = 0).

I can't do it during the OnPaint method because the text isn't selected at that time yet and if I just wait for the next OnPaint call it's quite obvious and ugly since you see all the combo boxes get highlighted one after another and then each one subsequently become unhighlighted.

Is this possible at all and if so how do I go about implementing it? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the text _looks_ selected because it's highlighted, but custom painting can highlight text that isn't actually selected (`SelectedText`). Which is it? Probably your custom combo box does something to cause this behaviour, because the native one doesn't: I'd study the differences to look for the cause, starting with the `OnPaint` handler (you could post it here).

Comment: This is a well-known bug in the native Windows combobox control implementation.  Most visible in a Winforms app when the window for the Form gets re-created.  Change the ShowInTaskbar property in a button's Click event handler for example.  Nothing you can do about it.  I think it got fixed in Windows 8, I can't repro it anymore.